# Unauthorized ajax POST to backend using FlaskWTF

Tags: python, ajax, fetch, flask-login, flask-cors

## Introduction

Hi. In this application, i am working on flask_login, fetch(), and flask_cors to predict what clothings are being predicted. All's fine only until when i try to log in using a registered user account.

---

## Problem

So currently, i have already created a user account and that he can do whatever predictions he wants in that account. So here, i have a snippet of a code whereby when the user clicks on the predict button with id `#startbutton`, it will send a POST to my flask backend, predict and return the predicted result.

```js
$("#startbutton").on("click", function(){
    let img = webcam.snap()
    $('#result').text( 'Predicting...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "http://localhost:5000/predict",
        data: img,
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').text('Predicted Output: ' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

And in my backend, i created a API route to handle the data coming from my javascript, and add the record into my database. In here, i used `@login_required` to verify the logged-in user and post his data to the database. I also added `@cross_origin` so that i can get the data coming from my ajax call.

```py
@app.route('/predict', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
@cross_origin(origin='localhost',headers=['Content-Type','Authorization'],supports_credentials=True)
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # get data from drawing canvas and save as image
        fileName, filePath = parseImage(request.get_data())
    
        # Decoding and pre-processing base64 image
        img = image.img_to_array(image.load_img(filePath, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(28, 28))) / 255.
        # reshape data to have a single channel
        img = img.reshape(1,28,28,1)
    
        predictions = make_prediction(img)
    
        ret = ""
        for i, pred in enumerate(predictions):
            ret = "{}".format(np.argmax(pred))
            response = results[int(ret)]

            # dump new entry into db
            new_entry = Entry(user_id=current_user.id, filename=fileName, prediction=response, predicted_on=datetime.utcnow())
            add_entry(new_entry)

            return response
    return render_template("index.html", index=True, nav=True)
```

In my `_init_.py` where i declare my app and CORS, i added `supports_credentials=True` so that CORS supports credentials for my app.

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, supports_credentials=True)
```

**However**, when i try to debug and attempt to run my app in localhost, i logged in with a existing user account, and tried to make predictions. But i will always end up with a `Error 401(Unauthorized)` error message, and when i go into google chrome console to see the error, i saw that it recognizes me as a anonymous user instead.

```sh
jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 POST http://localhost:5000/predict 401 (UNAUTHORIZED)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10099
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ index.js:49 <------- HERE
dispatch @ jquery-3.5.1.js:5429
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.5.1.js:5233
```

---

## Research

I tried to find if anyone encountered the same problem, and i managed to find one SO post that looks like the similar scenario as my current one. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50236564/flask-login-session-management-and-ajax). I tried to make sense of it but could not see (or comprehend) his final resolution.

---

## Edit

Ok so i tried to re-enact my current ajax code into Mozilla `fetch()`, which supposedly supports cookie (i guess?), but still eventually got a unauthorised message.

```js
$("#startbutton").on("click", function(){
    let img = webcam.snap()
    $('#result').text( 'Predicting...');

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      data: img,
      ContentType: 'application/json',
      credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      $('#result').text('Predicted Output: ' + data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
});
```

Would really *really, reallllly* appreciate if somebody can help me out! :( Thank You! :)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas hi i edited my post already. theres no "Traceback" error message since im using flask debugger, which i guess its because its not a pure python error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 3 days of misery, i came across an article which states that the ajax call is asynchronous by default, so in order to get the cookie, i just need to set `async` as `False`. And so i modified my ajax code to the snippet below:

```js
$("#startbutton").on("click", function(){
    let img = webcam.snap()
    $('#result').text( 'Predicting...');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "http://localhost:5000/predict",
        data: img,
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').text('Predicted Output: ' + data);
        }
    });
});
```

I know this is not the optimal solution(or is it lmao), so i am willing to see other alternatives to this.